# Modules not installed/found with conda install

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have an API from a website (subscription based), and they also have a module that they offer that must be used to access their data. I am trying to get this module to run on Spyder via the Anaconda environment.

The files of the module have been installed and downloaded via `pip install` and the computer recognizes them being installed as well. However, these two modules are not recognized by `conda install` and therefore my code will not run, even though the packages are downloaded and within the  > Anaconda3  > Lib with all other packages. (see attached picture for details of cmd and file locations).

Do you have any idea on how to get access to these modules and get them to run on my system? I tried another IDE totally outside of the Anaconda environment, and I still have the exact same problem.

[image: Shows that pip install recognizes modules and conda install does not, as well as the file location within Anaconda3]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Seems like the package ondemand does not exist for conda and using conda and pip interchangably you may not get all packages, check this link: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/574424/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda] ,  just try to do what the console suggests you to do, go to anaconda.org and check if the package is available for conda install.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. It appears that it is not available for conda install. So I should create a virtualenv and run this. Do you have an IDE you recommend for running this? I run all of my IDE through Anaconda, so this is new for me. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `pip` in Conda environments. `conda activate my_env`, `conda install pip`, `pip install <some packages>`.